# Is it better to roll all work into one loop or break it into several loops?

Tags: c++

I am parsing a folder structure that is quite heavy (in terms of the number of folders and files). I have to go through all the folders and parse any files I come across. The files themselves are small (1000-2000 characters although a few are bigger). I have two options:

> 1. Go through all the folders and files and parse any that I come
>      across in one big recursive loop.
> 2. Go through all the folders and store the paths of all the files
>      that I come across. The in another loop, parse the files by referring
>      to the stored file paths.

Which option would be better and maybe faster (the speed will most likely be I/O bound so most likely will not make a difference, but I thought I'd ask anyway)?

Comment: Boost filesystem namespace is convenient for things like this.

Comment: @AJG85: This is on a single platform which provides quite a few functions to handle this sort of thing, doing a relatively simple task. Dragging Boost into this would only knock build time up a few factors.

Comment: @peachykeen Not saying there is anything wrong with windows API file management functions. However proper dependency management should make build time a non-issue. I compile boost once a year when I update it and the dozen some odd libraries we use have increased our automated build by about 5 minutes with multiple architectures and platforms.

Comment: @AJG85: I am not allowed to use boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about one thread that creates the list of file names to process, and another thread that reads through that list of files and uses one of a handful of worker threads to do the processing?

I don't know how many directories there are, but just guessing that's not the big time sink.  I'd say you'd get the best performance by having a thread pool, each thread in the pool parsing a file (once you have the list of them.)  Because that stuff is gonna be so IO bound, the threading will probably make things far more efficient.

Comment: There is not much justification for introducing threads to a simple task unless the OP needs to parse millions of directories and files and can do so in parallel.

Comment: The OP is concerned with performance or he wouldn't have posted.  Yes, if he's gonna run this once, I say just write it as simply as possible and go get coffee while it runs.  If this thing has to run frequently and must be as efficient as possible, then this solution might help.

Comment: Being concerned with performance and identifying a performance bottleneck are two different things. This question falls under premature optimization and developers often cost far more than hardware. If shaving a few milliseconds or even seconds off an algorithm means a man-month of development is it still worth it? That depends entirely on elements unknown at present.

Comment: I get the concern about early optimization.  But a man month of development?  For this?  My assumption was that he'd done the initial analysis and was looking for ways to speed things up.  And honestly, threading the parsing of the files would not be a big deal.  Sometimes writing threaded routines of that nature leads to simpler, more straight forward code because you break things up into smaller, tighter units of work.  (Edit:  Now that I look again, he's doing this in C++ and Windows, so yeah, man month may be right. =)

Comment: @AJG85: Stackoverflow is very sensitive about premature-optimization. New comers may need to be aware of it but not people who have been asking questions for a long time (like me). I get it, premature optimization is BAD. But seriously, should I at least not pick the right route from the start when 2 or more routes are going to take the same time but one may deliver the fastest result and/or maintainable code (depending on what I am going after)? That is what the question was about. I can do both. But once I do it, and I find out the other choice was better, I'd have to spend hours...

Comment: .. figuring it out again especially if this task is months old. Why not pick the correct route from the start? Also, people on Stackoverflow need to realize that there are other developers here as well and not just enterprise developers. I develop games and work with game engines day in/out. We need the fastest possible code so that we can debug our game (which is NOT compiler optimized). If it is not fast, we cannot debug our game, end of story. Enterprise developers just do not understand this point and can't get past the fact that some developers REQUIRE premature optimization.

Comment: @Marvo: I actually went with this route (+1)... so I have to steal the checkmark from `In silico` (sorry!)

Comment: @Samaursa Sorry no offense meant was simply driving the point. I've worked in games, enterprise, and hardware and while writing the fastest possible code sometimes is absolutely necessary in those cases  the answer was rarely as simple as "throw some threads at it"

Comment: @AJG85: Agreed! And none taken, it is just that some of the questions that ask anything related to _speed_ or _optimization_ gets the close votes. It is like people have it in their feed and as soon as they see a question like that, they hit close without even reading the question or thinking about what the OP is doing

Comment: @Marvo: I don't know! Simply because I did not try it the other way (but as I mentioned earlier, I had a few options, all would take approx. the same amount of time to implement, so may as well go for the potentially one from the start)

Answer (score 7):

### You pick the option that gives you the most readable and the most understandable code.

Especially since the two options you provide are functionally identical. Seriously, you want to be able for others and yourself in the future to be able to look at it and have some clue as to what it does.

*"The most readable and the most understandable"* almost always means *"the simplest and the easiest way."* (Although some code is inherently complex. That's still not an excuse to write unreadable code.) Option 1 sounds easier to implement in my opinion, but try it for yourself. Profile for bottlenecks if it isn't fast enough.

Most likely, the actual disk I/O will take *much* longer than the total processor cycles or memory accesses needed for either option, so which option you take might not even be relevant. But the only way to know for sure how fast your programs are running and whether you need improvements is by profiling.

Answer (score 0):

The options seem to be functionally identical. I would say the consideration should be readability and maintainability - what is easier to understand and change later on when needed, expand or fix bugs in.

It is also worth considering breaking the functionality into separate objects - one is performing the search while the other is parsing the files found. Then you can run them concurrently and achieve better CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how deep the folder structure will be and how much data you'll have to hold in memory (including number of files/filenames).

If you have an extremely deep structure, you could run into a stack overflow. However, with path length limits, it's not very likely. You will have to store all the file names in memory, which is probably going to be a pain, but *probably* won't actually be a problem.

Assuming the functions are reasonable simply, it will likely be easier to simply call the recursive search function for each directory you find and the file parser for each valid file, all in a single loop:

```
function search_folder:
    for each item in curdir:
         if item is file:
            parse_file(item)
         else if item is folder:
            search_folder(item)
```

That gives you a relatively simple and very readable structure, at the cost of potentially deep recursion. Caching filenames and going through them later involves a lot more code and will likely be less readable, and (assuming you handle directories that same way) will have the same amount of recursion.

I'd go with #1, since it seems the more flexible and elegant solution.